# Prove $\sup\{|x -y| \mid x,y \in S\} = \sup S -\inf S$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Is the following a proof or an explanation?

Let $ S \subseteq\mathbb{R} $ be a nonemtpy and bounded set. We will define $ \operatorname{diam}\left(S\right) = \sup\{ \left|x - y\right| \mid x, y \in S \} $. We shall prove $ \operatorname{diam}\left(S\right) = \sup S -\inf S $.

Proof:

By the definition of supremum and infimum, $ \sup S $ is the minimum upper bound of $ S $ and $ \inf S $ is the maximum lower bound. Therefore, the distance from $ \sup S $ to $ \inf S $ is the greatest among the distances between elements in $ S $, whether $ \sup S, \inf S \in S $ or not, and therefore the statement is proven.

Comment: That's not a proof at all. This is an intuitive explanation, and not even a very convincing one. In order to prove you have to formally show that this number is an upper bound of the set you defined, and that there are no smaller upper bounds. And you have to be careful talking about a greatest distance, because supremum and infimum are not necessary maximum and minimum.

Comment: This proof is not satisfactory. To prove that the diameter is $\sup S-\inf S$, you need to show: 1) that $\sup S-\inf S\ge |x-y|$ for any $x,y\in S$; 2) that if $M\ge |x-y|$ for any $x,y\in S$ then $\sup S-\inf S\le M$.

Answer (score 1):

By translation, we can assume that $\inf S = 0$.

And by refletion, we can assume that $\sup S = 0$ or $\sup S > 0$.

If $\sup S = 0$, then $S = \{0 \}$. It is a trivial case.

Assume that $\sup S > 0$. We know that if $s \in S$ then $ 0 \le s \le \sup S$.
Thus $\sup\{|x -y| \mid x,y \in S\} \le \sup S$.

There is a non-negative sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$\lim a_n = 0$. Also, there is a non-negative sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
such that $\lim b_n = \sup S$. Because $\lim (b_n - a_n) = \sup S$,
we can say that $\sup\{|x -y| \mid x,y \in S\} \ge \sup S$.

From the above two fact, we obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid proof, it is too vague.

In order to show what you want, you need to use the fact that:

$$ y \geq \inf \mathbf{S}, \forall y \in \mathbf{S}, $$
$$-y \leq  - \inf \mathbf{S}, \forall y \in \mathbf{S}, $$

and,
$$ x \leq \sup \mathbf{S}, \forall x \in \mathbf{S}. $$
So now we have, that without loss of generality, assume $x\geq y$, then

$$ |x-y|\leq x-y \leq \sup \mathbf{S} - y \leq \sup \mathbf{S} - \inf \mathbf{S}$$

Comment: But how do we know it's the supremum